# MySQL increment field on insert

Tags: mysql, database

I have a **lists** table that has an *order* field.

When I insert a new record, is it possible to find the order of the previous row and increment the new row?

Or should I go about it myself in PHP by doing an OrderBy('order') query and getting the max() value of that?

Comment: PHP seems the better option.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a table with MySQL you can use an [auto-increment id](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html) so you won't have to deal about its incrementation:

```
CREATE TABLE people (
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

As explained [in the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html),

> An integer or floating-point column can have the additional attribute
>   `AUTO_INCREMENT`. When you insert a value of `NULL` (recommended) or 0
>   into an indexed `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, the column is set to the next
>   sequence value. Typically this is value+1, where value is the largest
>   value for the column currently in the table. `AUTO_INCREMENT` sequences
>   begin with 1.

I suggest you to ommit the field completly when inserting new records.

You can then retrieve the last id inserted with `LAST_INSERT_ID()` SQL function (or the [mysqli_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.insert-id.php) function of PHP languagefor example).

---

But since it's not what you wanted, probably because of one of the reasons quoted from [MarioZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7251627/marioz)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41599893/mysql-increment-field-on-insert/41599946?noredirect=1#comment70403383_41599946):

> If you are already using auto-increment for the ID you can use it for
>   the order (that can be one reason). For auto-increment the column
>   **must be set as primary and unique**, can't be repeated values. The auto-increment is from the number in the record, **if you inserted 10
>   rows and you delete 2, the next insert with auto-increment will be
>   11(if the last now is 8 you'd want it to be 9)**. Those are posible
>   reasons not to use it for what @Notflip wants :P

... You'll have to use PHP, with [`LOCK TABLE` and `UNLOCK TABLE` SQL instructions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables.html) before and after the retrieving of the last order then the updating of the new order, to avoid having simultaneous records with the same "order".

Comment: I mean a real 'order' field, like the order of things. god this is difficult haha. A column for sorting :) I know how AI works. thanks

Comment: OK, my bad, wan't clear from your question btw, you should add this to it ;)

Comment: ... OTOH, why an auto-increment wouldn't do the job?

Comment: If you are already using auto-increment for the ID you can use it for the order (that can be one reason). For auto-increment the column must be set as primary and unique, can't be repeated values. The auto-increment is from the number in the record, if you inserted 10 rows and you delete 2, the next insert with auto-increment will be 11(if the last now is 8 you'd want it to be 9). Those are posible reasons not to use it for what @Notflip wants :P

Comment: @MarioZ and Notflip, I've completed my answer.